# Easy Number Theory modular exponentiation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So I was reading through some old questions I found

For the question I was asked to explain why for $\,2018^{\large 2017^{\LARGE n}}\!\!\bmod 1001$

Where n is an integer between 14 million and 17 million

Why are there are only 4 possible values?

So I figured it out through taking 2017$^n$ (mod 720)  As 720 = phi(1001)

Using modular exponentiation I noted a few facts

2017$^1$ (mod720) ≡ 577

2017$^2$ (mod720) ≡ 289

2017$^4$ (mod720) ≡ 1

So therefore anything after this point will be congruent to 1 (mod 720)

So for example if I obtain 2017$^{15}$ = 2017$^8$ * 2017$^4$ * 2017$^2$ * 2017$^1$
Well this is just the same as 1 * 1 * 289 * 577 = 433(mod26)

And then I just finished the question by doing 2018$^{433}$ (mod 1001) ≡ 653

Now I just showed this with the 3 other patterns but basically I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to put this?

I feel like i'm there but it's not really a clean answer

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Your question is not very clear. What is the exact modulus? You should type your formulæ using Mathjax and make them clearer.

Comment: Well you take the first power (mod720) and then the full thing is took mod(1001)

Comment: If this really is about calculating the residues modulo $720$, then A) you should tell it at the beginning, B) this is duplicate of [this mother thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619).

Comment: And is it $2018^{(2017^n)}$  or $\bigl(2018^{2017}\bigr)^n$ that you try to calculate?

Comment: The first one mate

Comment: And why mod. $26$ comes in, towards the end?

Comment: I just took it mod26 to make it easier to calculate by hand

Answer (score 1):

Because of $\ \ \gcd(2018,1001)=1$, we can apply Euler's theorem and reduce the exponent modulo $\varphi(1001)=720$. The exponent is itself a power and because of $$2017^4\equiv 1\mod 720$$ which you found out, we can reduce $n$ modulo $4$. Hence there are only $4$ possible residues.

Comment: Does this answer not rely on the fact I already know there are only 4 possible answers though?

Comment: No, this is an easy consequence of the congruence you found out.

Comment: Sorry for being really dumb with this, Number theory isn't my strong point but why does 2017^ 4 ≡ 1 (mod720) imply there are only 4 solutions

Comment: OK, you want to know how to find out this congruence by hand, right ? I assumed that we can use this congruence, but I can try to work out a solution.

Comment: Well i'm just curious how we know the congruence you showed implies only 4 possible residues if that makes sense? Sorry if i'm not being clear

Comment: OK, lets start with the implication. You can write every positive integer $n=4k+m$ with $0\le m\le 3$. So, we have $$2017^n= 2017^{4k+m}=(2017^4)^k\cdot 2^m\equiv 2^m\mod 720$$ hence $2017^n$ must be congruent to one of the four powers $2017,2017^2,2017^3,2017^4$ modulo $720$

Comment: For the congruence itself , note $2017\equiv 1\mod 144$ , hence $2017^4\equiv 1\mod 144$. Since $2017^4\equiv 1\mod 5$ follows from Fermat's little theorem, using the chinese remainder theorem gives $2017^4\equiv 1\mod 720$

Comment: I probably should have written "one of the four powers $2017^0,2017^1,2017^2,2017^3$ modulo $720$" , nevertheless $2017^0$ and $2017^4$ have the same value modulo $720$ , namely $1$.

Comment: Ok thanks I think i'm following aha

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Theorem that you are implicitly applying.

**Theorem** $\ \ \color{#c00}{a^{\large n} \equiv 1}\pmod{\! m},\  \color{#0a0}{b^{\large k}\equiv 1}\pmod {\!n}\,\Rightarrow\, a^{\Large b^{\Large N}}\!\!\!\in \{a,\, a^{\large b},\, a^{\large b^{\Large 2}},\ldots\, a^{\large b^{\Large k-1}}\}\pmod{\!m}$

**Proof** $\ $ Dividing $\,N\,$ by $\,k\,$ yields $\ N = kq+R\ $ with $\,0\le R\le k-1.\,$

$\!\bmod n\!:\ \ \ b^{ N} =\, b^{\large R+kq} \,=\ b^{ R} (\color{#0a0}{b^{\large k}})^{\large q}\,\equiv\, b^{R}\, \color{#0a0}1^{\large q}\equiv b^{R},\:  $ so $\ b^N = b^R\!+ni\ $ thus

$\!\bmod m\!:\ a^{\large b^{\Large N}}\!\!\! = a^{\Large b^{\Large R}\! + ni}\! \equiv a^{\Large b^R}\! (\color{#c00}{a^{\Large n}})^{\Large i}\!\equiv a^{\Large b^R}\! \color{#c00}1^{\Large i}\equiv a^{\Large b^R}$

**Corollary** $\  a^{\Large b^{\LARGE N}}\!\!\equiv\,\color{#c00}a^{\Large \color{#0a0}b^{\LARGE N\bmod\color{#0a0} k} \!\bmod\color{#c00} n}\!\! \pmod{\!m}$